# If I want the child classes to add functionality to the parent class, should I make my attributes protected?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Say I have an `Image` class which performs manipulation on an image file, such as make the image black and white, gray-scale, etc. The image bytes are stored in an attribute which is an array. Now I want other programmers to add functionality to the `Image` class if they like to. I assume that this is done by creating their own class which inherits from `Image`. Examples of functionality that they could add would be rotate image, crop image, etc.

My question is what should I do in this case to allow other programmers to add functionality to the `Image` class, should I make the array that holds the image bytes `protected`, which will allow only child classes to modify it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Using protected attribute on the array and a public inheritance access specifier is best. This allows subclasses to keep the same public interface without having to expose too much implementation detail, and still allows the subclass the ability to modify the array.

Just as you suggested, that's what the access specifiers are for.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Classes/Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to consider whether there are any *invariants* that your class needs to maintain - for example, that the image member's dimensions aren't change by a derived class because separate `x`/`y` data members in the base class could get out of sync, or that a pointer to the data is not re-seated by the derived class because some other private member stores pointers into the data to track say brightest-pixel locations or whatever.  So, there's a process of deciding what kind of functionality belongs exclusively in your class, and what access you can grant to derived classes without it being easy to break your functionality.  You may still have to "trust" derived classes not to do weird things, but you should try to make it hard to do accidentally, and document your base class well.  If you want to learn about this kind of thing, you might reasonably start with the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).